# Executing raw sql queries in Play Framework

Tags: java, sql, playframework-2.0

I am using model classes to fetch records using find, insert records using obj.save() etc.

```
find.where().eq("email", email).eq("password", password)
            .findUnique();
```

How can raw queries be written instead to fetch the result into a bean object or list of bean objects as:

```
User user = "select * from user where email=" + email + " and password = " + password
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using `Ebean`, you could use something like the following:

```
String sql = 
 "select id, name from user where email=" + email + " and password = " + password;

RawSql rawSql =   
 RawSqlBuilder  
    .parse(sql)
    .columnMapping("id",  "user.id")  
    .columnMapping("name",  "user.name")
    .create();  

Query<User> query = Ebean.find(User.class);  
query.setRawSql(rawSql);  

List<User> list = query.findList();
```

If your query is more than a toy example, you will need to parameterize your input to prevent sql injection.

The [ebean docs](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery_rawsql.html) have more information on using raw sql.